# someone claims to have created such a malware, can he be true?

Tags: malware, antivirus, antimalware

These are not my lines they are by someone else on the internet. I also want to know is that malware that unique? How will it work in GPU and is there a way to sandbox such application?

"HERE GOES THE MALWARE........

> 1 More than 80% part runs only on GPU.......

so its useless to run that under sandbox

> 2 Around 90% of the virus is always in GPU memory......

To make the matter worse, you won't be able to debug that piece of code.....it does not use CUDA.....

> 3 The malware mutates in runtime, and that too, on GPU itself......CPU is not involved...

signature matching won't work....

> 4 The malware does not run as a process......
>
> 5 The malware rearranges its pieces in runtime......and becomes a full blown malware from an innocent piece of code.....
>
> 6 Different pieces of malware execute at totally different corners of system.......API Interception is not going to help.......not even at kernel level
>   SpyShelter will fail
>
> 7 The malware uses MCR techniques......your security suite gonna raise a hell lot of false positives..... "

and how can we access GPU memory?

Comment: An infected video driver?

Answer (score 1):

Malware can run mostly on GPUs to evade the detection by traditional approaches. One such proof-of-concept is provided in "[GPU-assisted Malware](http://dcs.ics.forth.gr/Activities/papers/gpumalware.malware10.pdf)". The authors demonstrate how to use General purpose computing on GPUs (GPGPU) to develop a malware which is self-unpacking and with run-time polymorphism.